# NodeJS how to get the Object a function belongs

Tags: node.js

some times code says it best. In below example code in `Chain.add` I have the function name and vars fed in to it.  But I am trying to reference the object that the function is associated with. How can I do this

```
class Chainable {
    constructor(...values) {
        this._chainableConstruct={
            name:   this.constructor.name,
            values
        };
    }
}

class Chain {
    constructor() {
        this.data=[];
    }

    add(func,vars) {
        console.log(func.name);     //returns fun
        console.log(...vars);       //returns test 45
        console.log(func.parent);   //return undefined want object t from line 28
    }
}

class Test extends Chainable {
    fun() {
        console.log("fun");
    }
}

let t=new Test();
let c=new Chain();
c.add(t.fun,["test",45]);
```

Comment: You can't. You've lost the reference to t when you passed a function. Consider explaining your case, this looks like XY problem. The code with dummy console calls doesn't show what result you're trying to achieve

Comment: Trying to get refrence to an object and a function in it.  Can call with object and function name seperate but seems ocward.

Comment: As said, this is XY problem. What is the real problem that you try to solve by accessing both object and function? To call it inside add?

Comment: Basically there will be a bunch of functions from objects I need to call.  However before I call them I need to store a backup in case system reboots part way through so they can be run at startup.  There are many ways I could do it but was thinking the above would be easiest to read

Comment: It could be solved by providing regular callback, e.g. `c.add(() => t.fun("test",45))`. Any way, what you ask about is impossible, this isn't how JS works. Consider reasking the question with more details that explain your case so the best way to solve it could be suggested, instead of addressing a specific implementation

Comment: above would never work.  Thank you for letting me know prefered method wont work.  will change to ```c.add(t,"fun",["test",45])```  not as clean but all the needed data is there

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, you can't. Furthermore, you can set property values of multiple objects with the same value, so the same function object might have multiple "parents".